# Installing applications on a separate USB

Tags: partitioning, usb, hard-drive, email

Recently made the switch by installing Ubuntu on my Chromebook. Love this community site, it has already answered so many questions, thank you for that. I have a 16gb internal harddrive, which is enough for Ubuntu, some apps, and a few files. I want to use Thunderbird as my e-mail client and this is where my troubles begin.

I have about 5gb of e-mails I don't want to lose, but storing that on my device fills up my entire drive. I feel there are a few options.

I've thoroughly researched the possibilities of upgrading my internal SSD, but as I've found it's not really possible as my model has a soldered harddrive on the motherboard.

I've asked around to see if running Ubuntu from a thumbdrive USB is a possibility, my only concern is if the performance is acceptable, is it?

And lastly, some sort of hybrid option. Is it possible to install Ubuntu on my harddrive and install apps on a USB stick? In this scenario my e-mails would be stored on a thumbdrive, whilst everything else is still stored on my harddrive.

Hopefully I've phrased my questions right, English is not my native language.

Comment: I don't know mailbird (it is also not in the repos, and on the website says that it is only for Windows), but doesn't it have an option like Thunderbird, [where it allows you to set a Local Folder](http://imgur.com/wy3wSjZ)? Moreover, doesn't it stores the data in your home? If so, you can simply move the /home on an external USB drive (buy a VERY good one, and be prepared for disaster anyway). Finally, usually chromebooks allow for SD cards. Why don't you use that instead of a USB? Obviously you need a VERY good one here also :)

Comment: Shoot, sorry! I mean Thunderbird! I'll edit it in my OP.

Comment: I edited my comment in the meanwhile :)

Comment: Well, Thunderbird has the option as mentioned above but the real question here is why do you think you need to use the old POP3 instead of IMAP with which you don't have to worry about local storage?!?

Comment: What are the benefits of using an SD card over an USB thumbdrive? Calculating the disaster that is imminent, does it really work that easy by just dragging the home folder to your external drive?

Comment: @CelticWarrior I am using IMAP, but it still downloads a copy of the e-mail on my device, or am I missing an option?

Comment: IMAP should be purely server based.

Comment: SD cards are usually faster, more reliable and easy to carry around than USB sticks. Also, an USB stick can be easily bumped and detach from the device while the SD is more inside, etc. Talking about IMAP, be sure to [configure your account correctly in Thunderbird](http://imgur.com/pHsECpK) (as default it saves the messages locally)

Comment: @dadexix86, that should do the trick for now, can't believe I missed that, thanks a bunch  (CelticWarrior too! :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the Thunderbird-profile-folder `~/.thunderbird` to the thumb-drive and create a symlink to the moved profile-folder in your home-directory. Then just make sure the thumb-drive is plugged in when you run Thunderbird.

Comment: Thank you, this seems like a good answer for any future applications that I might want to store on a thumb!

Comment: It really make sense for your 5 GB E-mails. I use POP3 with Thunderbird, I never leave my mails on the server, Big Brother is watching...

Answer (score 0):

Work out where your applications are stored with `which <commandname>` and move those directories to the usb and create a symlink to point the original directory to the new location on your usb.